# AWS Lambda (javascript): Extra key / level in returned value

Tags: javascript, json, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Not sure if this is a Lambda-specific issue, but I encountered it while moving a small project to AWS from Express/Node, so for now it's a Lambda problem. I should also mention that I'm still learning all things AWS, so this problem is likely due to my own lack of understanding. That being said, I need some guidance with a problem described like so:

The Lambda function calls out to a separate method and stores the result in a variable. The variable is returned as part of a simple response object, but is enclosed in an object with the key value of the stored variable name. This "stored variable" thing is unneeded and will break things later in the process.

**Here's some code and test output:**

The original Express / Node code:

```
try {
  const fetchResult = await axios(config)
  const result: Estimate = transformRecord(fetchResult.data) // <== SEPARATE METHOD STORES VALUE IN VARIABLE

  res.status(200).json(result) // <== CORRECTLY RETURNS JSON DATA

} catch (err: any) { // ... code block continues
```

The Lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  let response = {}

  try {
    let record = await transformRecord(event) // <== SEPARATE METHOD STORES VALUE IN VARIABLE

    response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      record   // <== HERE IS THE "EXTRA KEY VALUE" IN THE JSON DATA. REFER TO THE TEST OUTPUT BELOW
    };
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error('error in transformRecord: ', e);

    response = {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: e.message
    };
  }

  return response;
};
```

Here is enough of the test output to show the problem:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "record": {       // <== "record" IS THE UNNEEDED KEY VALUE 
    "watts": [      // <== "watts" SHOULD BE WHERE "record" IS
      {
        "2022-10-15": [
          {
            "time": "07:35:00",
            "watts": 0
          },
   // continues with more data that doesn't matter for this example
```

The "record" key can't be in the returned data, meaning that "watts" should be the next key after "statusCode", not "record". I suspect that the problem has something to do with how I am setting up and returning the "response" object, but just can't get my head around what I need to change, in order to make this work without the extra key "record".

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Best
m

Comment: How are you testing the lambda invocation? Through the api gateway? Then the status should not be there and the record will be top level. Through the lambda console? Then obviously the results is ***exactly*** what you return in the function.

Comment: I'm testing in the lambda console.

I think I understand what you mean with "...obviously the results...", but my question is about what I should do to not return the "record" key, while returning the rest of the JSON data.

Comment: Nothing. You tagged this with api-gateway as well, see what you get when you call this lambda through the gateway.

Comment: Alternatively just do `return record` instead but then your api gateway integration will no longer work.